# Seeing files that will be updated in Cornerstone

Tags: svn, cornerstone

Is there a way, in Cornerstone, to see what files will be update locally from SVN before doing so in Cornerstone?

Right now I jump to the command line and use

```
svn status -u
```

Seems like that is something that should be able to be done in the app and I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was looking for this option as well. I've emailed Zennaware support to see if there is a global preference for this option, but for now it seems that you have to set it for each working copy that you check out. First select the working copy, then in the menu select View > Show Repository Status. Alternatively, you can right-click on the working copy and select Show Repository Status. This also adds a new filter to the filter bar called "Newer in Repository".

Comment: Note that I got a reply from Zennaware and there is no global preference setting this as a default, so we will have to continue setting it for each working copy.